# MSSQL: varchar to float conversion error in insert query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is something that has puzzled me.

I have a SP with a TRY-CATCH and if it fails it should insert a record in an error log table with a message and some codes.
This is how it looks like:

```
INSERT INTO [Errors]
       ([application]
       ,[message]
       ,[extra])
 VALUES
       ('MySP'
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
       ,'InvNum=' + str(@inumber) + ' -- InvId=' + str(@IID) + ' -- Error Num: ' + str(ERROR_NUMBER()) + ' -- Error Line: ' + str(ERROR_LINE()))
```

The problem is that every time it tries to run this query it produces a varchar to float conversion error. It doesn't make sense for me because all the values passed in the last column are being converted to string.

Any idea?

Comment: The above isn't valid syntax; there's a missing `)` after `[extra]`.

Comment: As for the question, post a full [mre]. Though I would *guess* that one of your values in the `STR` function can't be converted to a `float` (likely `@inumber` or `@IID`).

Comment: @Larnu, I may have missed it when I was editing the SP to post here (there are more columns). In any case Daniel Gimenez fixed it. :-)

Comment: @Larnu, in reference to your second comment why a value wouldn't be possibly converted to a string?

Comment: It's not about converting it to a string, it's that the parameter, for `STR` isn't a valid `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the STR function "*Returns character data converted from numeric data*".  In other words, the parser knows that the STR function requires numeric parameters, so it is trying to convert all of your arguments into floats *first* and then the STR function will change them into strings.

Personally, I almost never use the STR function because of stuff like this, rather I prefer to use either `CAST(.. AS ..)` or `CONVERT(..)` because they 1) care less about the input data type and 2) can produce any output data type based on the parameters.  So rather than worry about which function I use to convert from data type (A) to data type (B), I always use the same function (CAST or CONVERT) and just have to worry about getting the parameters right.

Yes, it is true that CAST and CONVERT are a lot clunkier, longer and uglier, but if you just always use CONVERT than you only have to worry about how CONVERT works (also, CONVERT is super-general, you can use it for almost any scalar type conversion).

Comment: Oh I got it... it will produce the error whenever it finds a non-numeric character in the argument. Knowing that I can say that the parameter which is blowing the query is @inumber. In this case CAST(@inumber as varchar(20)) is the correct then. Thanks for the wonderful explanation @RBarryYoung!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `STR` function on several values and then concatenating the string with the string concatenation operator, use the `CONCAT` function.  It is pretty flexible with regards to what datatypes you pass into it and it should produce the same expected result.

```
INSERT INTO [Errors] ([application],[message],[extra])
VALUES (
  'MySP'
  , ERROR_MESSAGE()
  , CONCAT('InvNum=', 
     @inumber, 
     ' -- InvId=', 
     @IID, 
     ' -- Error Num: ',
     ERROR_NUMBER(),
     ' -- Error Line: ',
     ERROR_LINE()
  )
)
```